# couldn't open website visual studio

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010, web

I created new website(File->Create->WebSite) in visual studio 2010 and then tried to open this in other computer with visual studio 2010, however VS couldn't open the website saying "one ore more projects in solution were not loaded correctly" and output window tells: "website2 (it is name of the website) doesn't exist" despite that this exists.

Does someone know the solution of this?

Comment: Taking a guess, it sounds like on the first machine the website was attached to the local IIS instance, and on the second machine it's not set up that way.

Comment: Does any project is not stored in a separate file itself?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try following , It may help.
On your first computer , open the project , Right click on your WebSite and click open containing folder. copy your website from the folder to the new computer. open your project on second computer , remove the website which is not loading correctly and then add existing project to the solution. select the website which you just copied from the first computer.